# linux awk and grep specific lines for each datablocks

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a file with total 1000 lines, made up of 10 data blocks. Each data blocks have 100 lines. It looks like

```
.... 
      98
                                         0   -40237.30  16.89  19.51  90.00  90.00  90.00  90.00
Si   1.03311   4.82796  43.16361        1       -342.75159
O    1.83529   2.77329  49.93318        1        -96.97488
O    5.35427   0.19473  46.20120        1       -103.69066
O    2.45071   5.03078  49.23054        1        -99.25241
.....
O    6.14626  12.60099  40.48765        1       -103.96326
O   14.02932  16.70495  49.61010        1        -86.95440
      98
                                         50   -40226.57  16.89  19.51  90.00  90.00  90.00  90.00
Si   1.02182   4.80803  43.16740        1       -353.40357
O    1.85563   2.79949  49.91912        1        -96.85369
...
```

So it has a two header lines, and 98 data lines. '98' in header line means the number of data lines.

Here, I want to grep 5 lines, 1st, 11th, 56th, 78th, and 92th lines from each data block, and print them in the similar format with original file like

```
...

5

O   13.62134   8.31539  48.25986        1        -75.85881
O    9.01739   6.38846  50.60192        1         -2.55755
O   14.76930  15.88060  42.57059        1        -79.24684
Si   7.58364  10.90020  43.49788        1       -348.34842
Si  13.15177  12.05531  40.63252        1       -262.49178
5

O   11.01042  14.50491  45.42672        1        -45.13971
O    3.99057   0.69779  44.08524        1       -147.51776
O   11.84402   0.82791  40.78757        1        -92.14344
Si   4.80766  10.22501  49.57940        1       -297.04787
Si   6.14936  17.03883  40.37907        1       -209.38634
....
```

Like this. grep only 5 lines (1st, 11th, 56th, 78th, and 92th) from each data lines, and stack up like example right above. Result file will be total 70 lines, made up of 10 data blocks, and each data block have 7 lines (2 header line + 5 data line)

I have no problem with using 'grep' command to grep the specific line, but I don't know how to use grep in data-block-wise, and stack up like that. I was thinking of combination of awk and grep, but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Is that first (count) header the only line in the file with only a single field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another albeit similar way in awk

All of the numbers are +2 of the ones you said due to the two header lines before the first record

```
awk '(NR%100)~/^(3|13|58|80|94)$/' file
```

#### explanation

```
(NR%100)   If NR%100 (which will effectively loop every 100 from 0-99

~          Contains

^ $        Anchors so that only these exact values are used and not say 12 22 32 etc

|          regex or

()         a grouping
```

The default action in awk if there is no block after an argument is resolved is to print, so if the argument is true, i.e mod 100 equals any of the numbers, then the line is printed.

If you want to print 5 every first record(in regards to the 100)

```
  awk '(x=NR%100)==1{print 5"\n"}x~/^(3|13|58|80|94)$/' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
awk '
    {n = NR%100}
    n == 1 || n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 13 || n == 58 || n == 80 || n == 94
' file
```

This prints the 1st and 2nd lines (the headers) and the 1st, 11th, 56th, 78th, and 92nd lines of the 98-line block.

---

To change the headers:

```
awk '
    {n = NR%100}
    n == 1 {print "5"; next}
    n == 2 || n == 3 || n == 13 || n == 58 || n == 80 || n == 94
' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I modify inside awk to first header line? It should be '5', but n==0 of original file is '98'. I could use sed after this awk, but hope to finish in single command.

Comment: I thought the "header" was the first and last lines of the 100-line block, but it's the first and second. Answer updated.